# Problems importing own CA Certificate

Tags: 12.04, encryption, ssl, certificates

So, I have created my own little CA for my own purposes (inside my network, etc) and I know that the setup works (I can directly import the key into applications, and they connect to the server using the key fine).

But! When I tried to import the CA Certificate so that all applications can use it, they don't (firefox and chromium)

I have

- Placed the cacert.pem in /etc/ssl/certs and ran update-ca-certificates and dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
- Directly placed the cert inside the ca-certificates.crt file (As it wasn't being placed in there inspite of the previous commands)

I'm stumped.

Info:

Ubuntu Desktop, 12.04 x64

cat cacert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDCDCCAnG--snip--8guKJUzT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

openssl x509 -in cacert.pem -noout -text

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3 (0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=AU, ST=Western Australia, L=xx, O=xx, OU=Webmasters, CN=haven/emailAddress=xx
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec  8 11:47:37 2012 GMT
            Not After : Dec  6 11:47:37 2022 GMT
        Subject: C=AU, ST=Western Australia, L=xx, O=xx, OU=Webmasters, CN=haven/emailAddress=xx
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:xx:5b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                38:xx:95
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:38:xx:95

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         7b:xx:d3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My answer regarding ca-certificates [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121095/where-should-i-save-a-ca-certificate-that-is-used-by-a-single-user) might help.

Comment: You might find this answer on SU helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu/719047#719047

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing your certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates

Then modify /etc/ca-certificates.conf to include a reference to your new certificate.

Then run

```
update-ca-certificates
```

Update:

So done some more digging on this. It seems that firefox does not honour the /etc/ssl/certs database. Found [this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=316436) - its quite old but I believe it still to be the case.

As far as I can tell each user has their own cert database held in the cert8.db file in their profile directory. This can be updated using firefox directly (is their a reason for wanting to do this command line?) - but obviously each individual user will have to do this. Alternatively there is a command line way of doing this see [here](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27258/importing-pkcs12-p12-files-into-firefox-from-the-command-line). You could build a script to go through each user profile directory to do this (yuk!). Doesn't seem to be a "nice" way to do this for all users as far as I can tell.

Comment: No go, not showing in firefox's CA list. (did restart firefox)

Comment: However, while running an apt-get update for something else I saw that it wasn't complaining about my server's certificate being off...
EDIT: Nope, chrome and FF not picking it up...

Comment: Okay, thanks. The guide I was following was giving me the impression that there was a global location for CA certificates to be stored. Thanks anyways!