# "The PKCS #12 operation failed for unknown reasons." when importing personal digital certificates into Firefox

Tags: firefox, certificates

I am trying to import a personal digital certificate to Firefox (under Your certificates) and I am getting this error:

> The PKCS #12 operation failed for unknown reasons.

I am using **Firefox 72.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS**.
I already successfully imported this certificate into Firefox on Windows 10 and exported a backup (.p12).

What I have already tried:

- I made sure the password I am using is correct by checking that the output of `openssl pkcs12 -in myCertificate.pfx -noout` was `MAC verified OK`.
- I tried importing the certificate both as .p12 and .pfx files and I also tried setting a blank password if that would be the cause of the problem.
- I found [a very old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/198841) related to this, but I do not have the torbutton extension installed.
- I also tried importing the certificate using the terminal like this

```
    pk12util -i cert.pfx -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/randomchars.default
```

as mentioned in the linked bug report and in [another AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27258/importing-pkcs12-p12-files-into-firefox-from-the-command-line). 
I got `pk12util: PKCS12 IMPORT SUCCESSFUL` as a result, but I cannot see the certificate under "Your certificates" and neither in the output of `certutil -L -d sql:~/.mozilla/firefox/randomchars.default`

*Does anyone have another suggestion of where I could be going wrong?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to import the certificate by combining the answer linked above with [the one at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1373850/489136).

The command I used was:

> pk12util -i cert.pfx -d sql:/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/randomchars.default/

in which I substituted the username and randomchars accordingly.

It seems that the problem was that I hadn't specified that the certdir is a SQL database.

Answer (score 1):

I already did have a valid `pfx` file and could not import due to the error mentioned above. After quitting Firefox and staring with an empty session it suddenly worked.

I am using macOS and Firefox 78.0.2 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to install FILENAME.pfx under Ubuntu on Chrome or Firefox altough I had no problems installing the very same file on IE under Windows. What I did to solve the issue :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in FILENAME.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out FILENAMEcert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in FILENAME.pfx -nocerts -out FILENAMEkey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in FILENAMEcert.pem -inkey FILENAMEkey.pem -out FILENAME.p12
```

Then install FILENAME.p12 on Chrome or Firefox under Ubuntu should work like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (linux) delete or (rename) files key4.db (key3.db) and cert9.db (key3.db) in .mozilla/firefox/username. It works for me.